# updating multiple html elements with cakephp 2.0 js request

Tags: jquery, cakephp-2.0

I have successfully used Js->request to update 1 div. How do I update multiple divs with bits of information from the same request?
For eg.

I retrieve:
`array('Part' => array('name' => 'Test name', 'unitcost' => 5.55));`
 and I want to update `#name` with `['Part']['name']` and `#cost` with `['Part']['unitcost'].`

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no support for multiple updates within a single request as multiple responses are appended to the same request. However, it can be done out of CakePHP way i.e. using simple jQuery Ajax method and it will work as it should without any problem.